# BI SSRS Export to Excel generates text as a Number

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am having trouble with a field in my SSRS report. When i export the report to Excel i receive an error  that says *"We found a problem with some content in 'My Report'. Do you want us to try to recover?*.
The issue is i have a text field that Excel is treating as a Number. This field is not a number and will contain white spaces (which Excel ignores). Is there a way that i can format my text in my Report so that Excel treats it as a text on export and does not throw this error?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SSRS, so this may not be helpful, however prefacing a value in Excel with an apostrophe tells Excel to treat it as text. The apostrophe is not rendered to the user. Perhaps this might help?

Comment: I attempted this, after the export the apostrophe shows in the Excel data field(So the text looks like '29000060'). From my understanding SSRS exports directly what is on the Report when rendered as a .rdl file on the report server. So if it shows up in the field it will show up in the excel cell. Thanks for the good idea.

Comment: Try using CStr() on the field to make sure SSRS knows it is not a number.

Comment: This value still shows as a Number stored as Text.

Comment: Alright, this is actually by design. I stated it in  my original question incorrectly also. My column in the excel spreadsheet show an error of Number Stored as Text. The issue i had with this is basically that it is not an error and i did not want my end users opening up a report and seeing (Error would you like to recover). Being this this is by design there is not much i can do about it. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Also, here is the MSDN link explaining this issue. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5467ec7b-38cb-4e27-8fe6-57044e54cbf1/handle-text-numeric-values-in-ssrs-2008-while-export-to-excel?forum=sqlreportingservices